# How to change the icon for a BitLocker encrypted Drive Icon in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, icons, bitlocker, autorun

I've followed several guides for changing the icon of a USB drive, but none of them seems to work. My drive is encrypted with BitLocker. I can't get the icon to use my `.ico` file regardless of whether the drive is locked or unlocked.

Is there a way to show a custom icon for an unlocked BitLocker drive?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are trying to change the icon of a portable BitLocker drive, right? If it's internal drive, you can change the icon using the registry.

Comment: @DT yes, it's a portable USB drive with BitLocker and formatted with NTFS.